# Sticky Navbar lifting my footer when i touch the dropdown button when i am at the bottom of my page

Tags: javascript, html, css, atom-editor

So the thing is im working on a class website and im trying to make it look cool by adding various stuff to it. So the thing is that, i think some properties interrupt each other so whenever i use the dropdown toggle at any moment during the scroll, everything is fine, but when im at the footer and the resolution is lower than the original, the footer goes up and it goes back to the last section. Any tip on how to fix it or how to improve the overall order of my html? Thank you in advance!
Html, css and js involved in order:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="princ.css">

  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@600&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>SneakerReport</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  sticky-top">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SneakerReport</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Historia</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inscribete</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Marcas
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Supreme</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Palace</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
  </div>
</nav>

  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:100%">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="snk.jpg" alt="First slide">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>El inicio de algo grande</h5>

              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="snk2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>Una nueva experiencia</h5>
                  <p>Redescubre la moda</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="snk3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>Una accesibilidad unica</h5>
                  <p></p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>


<div class="main-text">
  <div class="col.md-12 text-center contenedor">
    <h1 style="font-size:70px">SneakerReport  <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i> </h1>
    <div class="reloj">
        <div class="display" style="text-align:center"> 17:19:50</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


  <section class="segmento">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class="column-left">
        <h1 class="text">
          Descubre la historia
        </h1>
          <p class="text">Conocerás la historia tras cada par, prenda o accesorio que alguna vez hayas podido ver, soñar o diseñar. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="column-right">
        <img src="sup.png" alt="Supreme" class="image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="segmento dos">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class="column-right">
        <img src="fog.jpg" alt="Fear of God" class="image" />
      </div>
      <div class="column-left">
        <h1 class="text">
          Compras guiadas
        </h1>
          <p class="text">Te traemos los mejores secretos para que compres lo que compres, siempre gane tu outfit y tu bolsillo. </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="segmento tres">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class="column-left">
        <h1 class="text">
          Sorteos mensuales
        </h1>
          <p class="text">Si te registras en nuestro boletin, pasaras a entrar en el sorteo mensual de una caja misteriosa. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="column-right">
        <img src="7v2.jpg" alt="Yeez" class="image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer class="footer segmento cuatro">
    <div class="footer-left">

      <img src="yzy.png" alt="snk">
      <p>SneakerReport nace como una solucion para que gente de todas las edades tenga una posibilidad
        de acceder a moda limitada sin pagar reventa.</p>
        <div class="socials">
          <a href="#" <i class=" fab fa-facebook"></i> </a>
          <a href="#" <i class=" fab fa-twitter"></i> </a>
          <a href="#" <i class=" fab fa-instagram"></i> </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="footer-right">
        <li>
          <h2>Paginas en las que tenemos soporte</h2>
          <ul class="box">
            <li><a href="#"> Supreme </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Palace </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h2>Otras secciones</h2>
          <ul class="box">
            <li><a href="#"> Historia </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Inscribete </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
      </ul>

      <div class="footer-bottom">
        <p>Todos los derechos reservados a &copy;Gonzalo Canteli 2020 </p>
      </div>
      </footer>
      <a class="btninicio" href="#"> <i class=" fas fa-angle-double-up"></i> </a>
      <div class="cookie-container">

        <p>Utilizamos cookies propias y de terceros para mejorar la experiencia del usuario a través de su navegación. Si continúas navegando aceptas su uso. <a href="#">Política de cookies. </a></p>
        <button class="cookie-btn">
          De acuerdo
        </button>


      </div>




    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="cookieplugin.js"></script>
    <script src="zap.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Css:

```
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;

}

.main-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 96.66666666666666%;
    color: #FFF;
}
.cookie-container{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #2f3640;
  color:#f5f6fa;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 16px rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.151);

  transition: 400ms;
}
.cookie-container a {
  color: #f5f6fa;
}
.cookie-container.active {
  bottom: 0;
}
.cookie-btn {
  background: #e84118;
  border:0;
  color:#f5f6fa;
  padding: 12px 48px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.marcos{
  border: 3px;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
}
.quitarpad{

    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}
#pagina{
  background-image: url("bg.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;


  margin: 0px;
}
#pagina p{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
#gradiente{




  background: rgb(167, 255, 55);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(167, 255, 55) 0%, rgb(255, 246, 232) 55%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(167, 255, 55) 0%, rgb(255, 246, 232) 55%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(167, 255, 55) 0%, rgb(255, 246, 232) 55%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(167, 255, 55) 0%, rgb(255, 246, 232) 55%);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(167, 255, 55) 0%, rgb(255, 246, 232) 55%);


  opacity: 0.9;
}


.contenedor h1{

  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-family: "Oswald script=latin rev=1", sans-serif;
}
h3{
  text-shadow: 2px -2px 0px rgba(147, 150, 150, 1);
}
.container{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-nav > li{
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
}
section{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  position:sticky;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
section .container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height:95vh;
  padding 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);
}
section .text {
  color:#fff;
}
section .image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  max-height:400px;
}
.column-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}
.column-left{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0rem 2rem;
}
.column-left h1{
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-style: italic;
}
.column-left p{
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
.segmento{
  background: #66488f;
}

footer{
  margin: 0;
  position: sticky;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  background-color:  #000033;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.footer-left img{
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.socials{
  text-align: center;
}
.footer > *{
  flex: 1 100%;
}
.footer-left{
  margin-right: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.footer-right{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.footer-right > *{
  flex: 1 50%;
  margin-right: 1.25em;
}
.box a{
  color:#999;
}
.footer-bottom{
  text-align: center;
  color: #999;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.footer-left p{
  padding-right: 20%;
  color: #999;
}
.socials a{
  background: #364a62;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}



.footer h2{
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.footer ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.footer li{
  line-height: 2em;
}
.footer a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dos{
  background: #f5e2c0;
}
.tres{
  background: #ff8543;
}
.reloj{
  text-align: center;
  background: none;
  height: 120px;
  width:500px;
  line-height: 200px;

  padding: 0 700px;


}
.reloj .display{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

nav{
  background-color: #000033;

  opacity:0.95;

}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
  .footer-right > *{
    flex:1;
  }
  .footer-left{
    flex:1 0px;
  }
  .footer-right{
    flex:2 0px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px){
  .footer{
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
.btninicio{
  position:fixed;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background: #6F1E51;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color:white;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

js:

```
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

gsap.utils.toArray('.segmento').forEach(section => {
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: section,
    start: 'top top',
    pin: true,
    pinSpacing: false
  });
});
setInterval(function(){
const reloj = document.querySelector(".display");
let time = new Date();
let sec = time.getSeconds();
let min = time.getMinutes();
let hr = time.getHours();
if (sec < 10){
  sec= '0' + sec;
}
if (min < 10){
  min= '0' + min;
}
if (hr < 10){
  hr= '0' + hr;
}
reloj.textContent = hr + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your footer style you have to add `bottom: 0;` to keep it sticky at the bottom of the page
try the snippet

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

gsap.utils.toArray('.segmento').forEach(section => {
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: section,
    start: 'top top',
    pin: true,
    pinSpacing: false
  });
});
setInterval(function(){
const reloj = document.querySelector(".display");
let time = new Date();
let sec = time.getSeconds();
let min = time.getMinutes();
let hr = time.getHours();
if (sec < 10){
  sec= '0' + sec;
}
if (min < 10){
  min= '0' + min;
}
if (hr < 10){
  hr= '0' + hr;
}
reloj.textContent = hr + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
});
```

```css
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;

}

.main-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 96.66666666666666%;
    color: #FFF;
}
.cookie-container{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #2f3640;
  color:#f5f6fa;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 16px rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.151);

  transition: 400ms;
}
.cookie-container a {
  color: #f5f6fa;
}
.cookie-container.active {
  bottom: 0;
}
.cookie-btn {
  background: #e84118;
  border:0;
  color:#f5f6fa;
  padding: 12px 48px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.marcos{
  border: 3px;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
}
.quitarpad{

    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}
#pagina{
  background-image: url("bg.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;

  margin: 0px;
}
#pagina p{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
#gradiente{




  background: rgb(167, 255, 55);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(167, 255, 55) 0%, rgb(255, 246, 232) 55%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(167, 255, 55) 0%, rgb(255, 246, 232) 55%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(167, 255, 55) 0%, rgb(255, 246, 232) 55%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(167, 255, 55) 0%, rgb(255, 246, 232) 55%);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(167, 255, 55) 0%, rgb(255, 246, 232) 55%);


  opacity: 0.9;
}


.contenedor h1{

  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-family: "Oswald script=latin rev=1", sans-serif;
}
h3{
  text-shadow: 2px -2px 0px rgba(147, 150, 150, 1);
}
.container{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-nav > li{
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
}
section{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  position:sticky;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
section .container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height:95vh;
  padding 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);
}
section .text {
  color:#fff;
}
section .image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  max-height:400px;
}
.column-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}
.column-left{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0rem 2rem;
}
.column-left h1{
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-style: italic;
}
.column-left p{
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
.segmento{
  background: #66488f;
}

footer{
  margin: 0;
  bottom:0;
  position: sticky;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  background-color:  #000033;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.footer-left img{
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.socials{
  text-align: center;
}
.footer > *{
  flex: 1 100%;
}
.footer-left{
  margin-right: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.footer-right{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.footer-right > *{
  flex: 1 50%;
  margin-right: 1.25em;
}
.box a{
  color:#999;
}
.footer-bottom{
  text-align: center;
  color: #999;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.footer-left p{
  padding-right: 20%;
  color: #999;
}
.socials a{
  background: #364a62;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}



.footer h2{
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.footer ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.footer li{
  line-height: 2em;
}
.footer a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dos{
  background: #f5e2c0;
}
.tres{
  background: #ff8543;
}
.reloj{
  text-align: center;
  background: none;
  height: 120px;
  width:500px;
  line-height: 200px;

  padding: 0 700px;


}
.reloj .display{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

nav{
  background-color: #000033;

  opacity:0.95;

}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
  .footer-right > *{
    flex:1;
  }
  .footer-left{
    flex:1 0px;
  }
  .footer-right{
    flex:2 0px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px){
  .footer{
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
.btninicio{
  position:fixed;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background: #6F1E51;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color:white;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@600&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  sticky-top">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SneakerReport</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Historia</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inscribete</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Marcas
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Supreme</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Palace</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
  </div>
</nav>

  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:100%">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="snk.jpg" alt="First slide">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>El inicio de algo grande</h5>

              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="snk2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>Una nueva experiencia</h5>
                  <p>Redescubre la moda</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="snk3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>Una accesibilidad unica</h5>
                  <p></p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>


<div class="main-text">
  <div class="col.md-12 text-center contenedor">
    <h1 style="font-size:70px">SneakerReport  <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i> </h1>
    <div class="reloj">
        <div class="display" style="text-align:center"> 17:19:50</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


  <section class="segmento">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class="column-left">
        <h1 class="text">
          Descubre la historia
        </h1>
          <p class="text">Conocerás la historia tras cada par, prenda o accesorio que alguna vez hayas podido ver, soñar o diseñar. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="column-right">
        <img src="sup.png" alt="Supreme" class="image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="segmento dos">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class="column-right">
        <img src="fog.jpg" alt="Fear of God" class="image" />
      </div>
      <div class="column-left">
        <h1 class="text">
          Compras guiadas
        </h1>
          <p class="text">Te traemos los mejores secretos para que compres lo que compres, siempre gane tu outfit y tu bolsillo. </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="segmento tres">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class="column-left">
        <h1 class="text">
          Sorteos mensuales
        </h1>
          <p class="text">Si te registras en nuestro boletin, pasaras a entrar en el sorteo mensual de una caja misteriosa. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="column-right">
        <img src="7v2.jpg" alt="Yeez" class="image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer class="footer segmento cuatro">
    <div class="footer-left">

      <img src="yzy.png" alt="snk">
      <p>SneakerReport nace como una solucion para que gente de todas las edades tenga una posibilidad
        de acceder a moda limitada sin pagar reventa.</p>
        <div class="socials">
          <a href="#" <i class=" fab fa-facebook"></i> </a>
          <a href="#" <i class=" fab fa-twitter"></i> </a>
          <a href="#" <i class=" fab fa-instagram"></i> </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="footer-right">
        <li>
          <h2>Paginas en las que tenemos soporte</h2>
          <ul class="box">
            <li><a href="#"> Supreme </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Palace </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h2>Otras secciones</h2>
          <ul class="box">
            <li><a href="#"> Historia </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Inscribete </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
      </ul>

      <div class="footer-bottom">
        <p>Todos los derechos reservados a &copy;Gonzalo Canteli 2020 </p>
      </div>
      </footer>
      <a class="btninicio" href="#"> <i class=" fas fa-angle-double-up"></i> </a>
      <div class="cookie-container">

        <p>Utilizamos cookies propias y de terceros para mejorar la experiencia del usuario a través de su navegación. Si continúas navegando aceptas su uso. <a href="#">Política de cookies. </a></p>
        <button class="cookie-btn">
          De acuerdo
        </button>


      </div>




    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="cookieplugin.js"></script>
    <script src="zap.js"></script>
```